# How to trace request that caused CPU spike in ASP.Net MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have an ASP.Net MVC based web app that has been running for a number of years now.  Every once in a while, the W3WP process jumps to 90+% CPU usage and stays there for round about an hour.

During that time other requests become dog-slow and my users start complaining of the system becoming non-responsive.  Most of the time our techies then recycle the app pool in IIS and that resolves the problem and all are happy again. Other times our techies are unavailable and it comes right by itself - that's when I've used our logging to find that the spike lasts anything from 45 minutes to 2 hours.

Please advise what kind of logging can I put in place to tell me what the culprit request is that is causing the spike.  I've taken a look at request logs in the moments before the spike and nothing stands out.  But the logging I have may be missing the culprit request.  I'm thinking is there perhaps a way in the serving of a request to log how much memory/cpu it used, or something like that?

Comment: If I recall correctly, [System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx) is meant for this purpose. But I'm not sure what's the proper way to continuously monitor this in ASP.NET without causing performance issues (haven't tried).

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/debugging-a-memory-leak-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application/) or [this](http://mvolo.com/fix-the-3-high-cpu-performance-problems-for-iis-aspnet-apps/) may help you.